# Listening to PropertyChanged using MVX

Tags: c#, listener, mvvmcross

I can listen to specific properties using MvvmCross using a listener. How do I listen to all properties of my class, and (alternatively) all properties of a specific object?

```
_listener = new MvxPropertyChangedListener(this);
_listener.Listen(() => HighlightText, sourceHandler);
_listener.Listen(() => SearchText, sourceHandler);
```

The current method works well because I can easily rename the Property name.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is probably to subscribe yourself using code from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxPropertyChangedListener.cs

```
 _token = _ViewModel.WeakSubscribe(OnPropertyChanged);

 private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 { 
      // your code - may or may not use e.PropertyName
 }
```

You can easily do this on any INotifyPropertyChanged object - and (conventionally) your event handler should only be invoked on the ui thread.